# Для чего используется функция NewType() из модуля typing?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не могу схватить идею для чего используют функцию [NewType()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#distinct) из модуля typing.

В [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html):

> Use the NewType() helper function to create distinct types:
>
> ```
> UserId = NewType('UserId', int) 
> some_id = UserId(524313)
> ```
>
> The static type checker will treat the new type as if it were a subclass
>   of the original type. This is useful in helping catch logical errors:
>
> ````
> def get_user_name(user_id: UserId) -> str:
>     ...
>
> # typechecks 
> user_a = get_user_name(UserId(42351))
>
> # does not typecheck; an int is not a UserId 
> user_b = get_user_name(-1) ```
> ````

В [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#newtype-helper-function):

> There are also situations where a programmer might want to avoid
>   logical errors by creating simple classes. For example:
>
> ```
> class UserId(int):
>     pass
>
> get_by_user_id(user_id: UserId):
>     ...
> ```

Какие логические ошибки имеются ввиду?
Какая выгода от создания дополнительного типа `UserId` и использования его вместо `int`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например вы можете по ошибке передать в `get_by_user_id` идентификатор группы, а не пользователя. Без типа ошибка не будет замечена, и то и другое - `int`.

Comment: Так чтобы передать в  `get_by_user_id()` идентификатор группы объект типа `UserId` мы должны создать объект типа `UserId` воспользовавшись `UserId()`. А не, например,  `GroupId()`. Т.е. мы знаем, что некоторое id является именно идентификатором пользователя, а не группы, и соответственно зачем тогда использовать `UserId` если можно сразу передать `int`?

Comment: Чем больше становится приложение и чем больше людей над ним работает, тем меньше соответствует действительности "мы знаем, что некоторое id является именно идентификатором пользователя". В реальном приложении данные могут пройти через несколько слоёв логики и несколько десяткой методов, больше половины которых писали разные люди и в разные годы.